# Libraries that provide updatable settings

Tags: c#, architecture, settings

Do you know any kind of .NET libraries, which provide persistent settings that are:

1. May have versions and may upgrade from version to version. By upgrading I mean loading defaults ONLY for mismatched fields and loading matching fields.
2. Provide some load info, so one could find out what fields were loaded (or mismatched or something like this).
3. May have custom scopes (We have 4 scopes of settings in desired architecture)
4. Have kind of Configurator behaviour or at least binding possibilities.
5. And it would be good (but not required) to have possibility to easily read and change the settings files, like xml stored settings for example.

Unfortunatelly Properties.Settings nor pure XmlSerialization doesn't satisfy this requirements. 
We have an application with about 800 setting fields, 4 scopes (user, application, machine, special device). Today we use a combination of approaches to store all of it. But from version to version it became harder and harder to maintain.

I think, the requirements I posted are quite typical. At least I don't believe that we are the first in the world who need such thing. But I was unable to find any library of such kind. Could you suggest some?

Comment: It sounds like your underlying problem might be design - not a lack of libraries.  I don't get enough context from your question to know what the right solution would like.

Comment: I'm not asking this question because I'm in trouble with some project (even if we are). I always thought that Properties.Settings are not so flexible. I mean there are interfaces, you can reimplement, but when you do, you'll brake every handy stuff in Properties.Settings. Imagine (without even having versions and custom scopes) you have 200 config fields, it is crazy to work with such amount in builtin designer. You create custom settings files to have some 'categories', but then you have save them at one time. 200 not 800. And I can speak a lot of why they are not flexible.

Comment: So I just thought that maybe somebody already did something. At least solutions like configuration sections designer for ASP.NET exist.

Comment: For a configuration section designer you could try the config editing tool that comes with EntLib - but I've never used it for that purpose myself (in recent times at least).

Comment: The configuration section designer for EntLib is only for EntLib configurations. Here is an open source configuration designer   http://csd.codeplex.com/

Comment: How fluid are your scope schemas? If you can schema-constrain XML (XSD), writing a wrapper that cascades settings is an engineering -- i.e., not R&D -- task. I've done this more than once with XSD, if that's an option I may be able to provide working code.

Comment: Actually it is exactly the option we are looking into right now. If you can provide enything that is relevant (code, design etc) it would be VERY helpfull.